# Format date in Rules

Tags: datetime, tokens

I'm using a rule to send out emails when a node is created. Under *Action* and *Message body*, I insert [node:field_calendar_date]. The token is replaced with (for example) "2012-12-14T08:00:00" in the email message, but I would like it to be replaced with "Friday, December 14, 8:00am" (same date, but a different format).

I tried to follow [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7), but it doesn't work.

How can I get the format I want?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `[node:field_calendar_date:custom:l, Fd, gia]`, if `[node:field_calendar_date]` is a date token. In that case, `[node:field_calendar_date:custom]` returns the date in the custom format listed after the following colon. The format string is the one accepted by [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

If you want to use the format set as short/medium/long format set in the Drupal date settings, then you can use the following tokens:

- `[node:field_calendar_date:short]`
- `[node:field_calendar_date:medium]`
- `[node:field_calendar_date:long]`

Comment: i tried and the email message renders
[node:field_calendar_date:short]
or any of the tokens used

Answer (score 8):

OK, got it, it is not working even if I do not really understand the logic under the hood...
Actually, the two blocking issues I had were the following:

1. A date may be a range, therefore [node:field_date] cannot be considered as a date token. Install [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) and enable the module "Entity tokens" to get access to the actual date value,
2. Beware that for an obscure reason Entity token replace the underscore ([node:field_date...) of the original tokens name by a dash ([field-date...), you will then have access to a properly formatted date (in my case "[node:field-date:value:custom:Ym]", in the original question I guess therefore "[node:field-calendar-date:value:custom:l, F d, gia]")

Comment: Well thats just annoying - duplicating all the tokens to provide alternate functionality. Thanks for the tip of (point 2)

Comment: Point 2 did it for me too. I never would have thought to try dashes!